# Google Apps Engine PHP - how to hide included scripts

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app.yaml

lets say one have this index.php

```
<$php
include_once("dictionary.php");
...
$>
```

how must app.yaml be defined to upload "dictionary.php" but in a not exposed-way ? (the following example let users to browse http://mydomain/dictionary.php, which is what we want to avoid)

```
application: myGAEphpapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /    
  script: /index.php

- url: /dictionary\.php    
  script: /dictionary.php
```

Comment: Why are you including it as a handler in the first place? Doesn't `include_once` work server side, and thus there's no need to make it public?

Comment: i dont unnderstand your question: how do you upload dictionaty.php to GAE servers if you dont declare it on app.yaml ?

Comment: Everything in your directory will be uploaded.

Comment: understood. so why does exist "static_files", and app_readable declarations ?

Comment: The purpose of static files is to move them to a CDN, so they won't be available from your app but requests won't hit your server either.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found is to define the non-exposed scripts *after* a handle that gets all requests

```
application: myGAEphpapp
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /    
  script: /index.php

[...]

**- url: /.*
  script: /catchall_script.php**

#never triggered but serverside available
- url: /dictionary.\php
  script: /dictionary.php
```

Comment: This is completely useless, if you can't hit a url then there's no point in having a handler for it. Just remove it and everything will work the same.